# COPY in dockerfile changes from expected user to root user

Tags: docker

I've hit a wall on trying to user the COPY command in a dockerfile. When building with --privileged, it's not a problem, but that switch is not viable from a security standpoint. Here's what's happening:

1. List the files on the host -> they all show as user123
2. Show user name and uid/gid in the container -> they all correspond to user123
3. Issue a COPY inside the container
4. List the files inside the container -> they all show as root

For the last item above, I would like the files to show as user123.

I've tried/confirmed the following:

- Create and set the userid/groupid in the dockerfile using groupadd/useradd/USER
- Set USER in docker file by name
- Set USER in docker file by id's
- Pass in uid/gid from host to dockerfile via ARGS
- chown the files after the COPY -> access denied
- Confirmed host user is a member of the docker group

I've also tried COPY --chown in the dockerfile, but that option isn't available because the docker server version is stuck in the stone ages (1.13).

To state the obvious, this is occurring during a docker build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use `COPY --chown` why don't you `RUN` chown after copy?

```
RUN chown -R 123:123 file
```

Also why do you have to build the image on the server? You can build it elsewhere, where a more recent Docker version is available. Then deliver the image to the server via repository or through export/import.

Comment: I have tried RUN chown... Access denied. I'll add that to the original info. It must be run on the server because bits that make it to production have to be created in a controlled environment due to the product's high security needs.

Comment: @GaTechThomas First run chown, then change `USER`. `chown` can only be used by root.

Comment: I'll give that a try now.

Comment: That did it! At least on the build. The run now gets permission denied on all those files that have been chowned to user123. Back to it...

Comment: @GaTechThomas have you changed `USER` back to 'user123' after chown? If you did, then add the run command that you use and the Dockerfile to your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean the docker run, separate from the docker build. Do you think that should be a different SO question?

Comment: @GaTechThomas I can guess but without Dockerfile, the log output, and the command that you use it can take a long time. Add these to the question and I'll see.

Comment: Thanks much... Full day of other work here, so it will likely be a while before I can get back to it.